# Is the language of TMs running in polytime Turing-recognizable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Any ideas for proving that $L=\{\langle T \rangle : \text{ time complexity of $T$ is polynomial}\}$ is not Turing-recognizable?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: I tried to assume opposite which led me nowhere, also I tried looking at its complement which doesn't look useful, and I tried to see if it's equivalent to $A_{TM}^C$ which it's not

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please don't use the 'Your Answer' box to respond to requests for clarification.  Instead, revise your question using the 'edit' button under your question so the question reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Please use the 'Your Answer' box only for material that directly answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You can reduce the complement of halting problem to this language.

An instance $\langle M,w\rangle$ is reduced to a TM $M_w$ that works as follows.

On input $x$:

1. Run $M$ on $w$.
2. If $M$ does not halt after $|x|$ steps, *accept*; otherwise, *go into an infinite loop*.

Now it remains for you to show the correctness of this reduction to complete the proof.